# Javascript's Array Reverse

Tags: javascript, arrays

How exactly does Javascript's `array.reverse()` work?  Does it go through and swap every element of the array?  If so, does it take O(n) to swap an array of size n?

I guess the reason I am asking is because I was wondering if `array.reverse()` was the same as:

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length / 2; i++) {
  var holder = a[i];
  a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
  a[a.length - 1 - i] = holder;
}
```

**NOTE**:  Sorry if the Javascript code I posted is incorrect, it's pretty late right now.

**EDIT**:  Fixed `a.length` to `a.length / 2`.

Comment: It's incorrect because by traversing the array in full, you'll swap all the elements twice and return to the original array. Use `a.length / 2` (integer division of a.length and 2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the full details of how it works, [read the relevant section of the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.8). Here's the algorithm:

> 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.
>
>    2. Let lenVal be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument "length".
>    3. Let len be ToUint32(lenVal).
>    4. Let middle be floor(len/2).
>    5. Letlower be 0.
>    6. Repeat, while lower ≠ middle
>
>       1. Let upper be len−lower −1.
>       2. Let upperP be ToString(upper).
>       3. Let lowerP be ToString(lower).
>       4. Let lowerValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument lowerP.
>       5. Let upperValue be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of O with argument upperP .
>       6. Let lowerExists be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument lowerP.
>       7. Let upperExists be the result of calling the [[HasProperty]] internal method of O with argument upperP.
>       8. If lowerExists is true and upperExists is true, then
>       9. Call the [[Put]] internal method of O with arguments lowerP, upperValue, and true .
>       10. Call the [[Put]] internal method of O with arguments upperP, lowerValue, and true .
>       11. Else if lowerExists is false and upperExists is true, then
>       12. Call the [[Put]] internal method of O with arguments lowerP, upperValue, and true .
>       13. Call the [[Delete]] internal method of O, with arguments upperP and true.
>       14. Else if lowerExists is true and upperExists is false, then
>       15. Call the [[Delete]] internal method of O, with arguments lowerP and true .
>       16. Call the [[Put]] internal method of O with arguments upperP, lowerValue, and true .
>       17. Else, both lowerExists and upperExists are false
>       18. No action is required.
>       19. Increase lower by 1.
>    7. Return O .

Answer (score 3):

The actual algorithm is almost similar to what you specified. Just change your `for` loop to iterate only upto `a.length/2` and it would be similar to what `Array.reverse` would do. I am skipping the inner details here for the sake of simplicity. So it would be

```
for(var i = 0; i < a.length/2; i++) {
  var holder = a[i];
  a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
  a[a.length - 1 - i] = holder;
}
```